# No hat for using Android app?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2014

I'm using the app to type this. .. I've come from Stack Overflow, where I did some reading.    As  yet, there is no sign of [Bugdroid](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/bugdroid) in my hat list,  either here or there.

Comment: Ok - now Bugdroid has showed up in my Meta list, but not at StackOverflow.  Does this mean that you need to ask a question using the app to get it?   What about "on the road" then?

Comment: Yes, the hats are awarded per-site. You can wear any hat on any site though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full description of Bugdroid is:

> post, vote, edit, or comment with the Android app

You did some reading on Stack Overflow, but you don't get the hat for reading something.

Comment: Where do you read the full descriptions?

Comment: @GreenAsJade On the Winterbash site, click on a hat.